# Getting post values after submit

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

There is form with method POST.

```
 <form action="<?echo base_url("user/reg_user");?>" name="register" method="post" >
```

When I click at sumbit, all data will return to controller "user" with GET method in my url.

POST array is " ".

Please, help me to understand where my fault.

I have already tried to use form helper, but it did not worked. Only automatic GET array.

Comment: What ' base_url("user/reg_user");' return?

Comment: <form action="reg_user.php" name="register" method="post" > You must call some script for data processing

Comment: have you tried `<form method="POST" action="<?php echo site_url('user/reg_user'); ?>" name="register">`?

Comment: avoid to use short tags <? ?>, write full tag <?php ?>. still if you want to use it, then it need short_open_tag enabled in php.ini. It's not recommend. The short syntax is deprecated, and if you want to make your application portable, it's possible that short open tags are not allowed on another server and hence your application will break.

Comment: if you are using php 5.5 then you can use short code <?= base_url("user/reg_user"); ?>

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter has its own helper class to deal with forms. you can either autoload it in autoload.php or load it on demand.

```
$this->load->helper('form');
```

Once you loaded the helper class you can use the **form_open()** method to create forms on your Views. If your form needs to upload files then you can use **form_open_multipart()**

Here's a simple example. If you want to send the username and password from your login view to the login function written in the user controller, you would likely to create a login form as follows:

```
echo form_open('user/login');
```

The above example would create a form that points to your base URL plus the "user/login" URI segments, like this:

```
<form method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" action="http:/example.com/index.php/user/login" />
```

here is a full example of a login page(view). I removed the extra html tags used for allignments to make short.

```
<?php echo form_open(); ?>

<?php echo form_input('name', set_value('name', $user->name)); ?>
<?php echo form_input('email', set_value('email', $user->email)); ?>    
<?php echo form_password('password'); ?>
<?php echo form_password('password_confirm'); ?>
<?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Save'); ?>

<?php echo form_close();?>
```

Once the user send the data we can access it from the controller or from the model (it depends on your logic). anyway the following is the login function in my example.

```
public function login ()
{
    $user = $this->get_by(array(
        'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
        // 'password' => $this->input->post('password'),
         'password' => $this->hash($this->input->post('password')),
    ), TRUE);

    if (count($user)) {
        // Log in user
        $data = array(
            'name' => $user->name,
            'email' => $user->email,
            'id' => $user->id,
            'loggedin' => TRUE,
        );
        $this->session->set_userdata($data);
    }
}
```

So the point is you can access the data which is posted by the form in the following way

```
$email = $this->input->post('email');
```

Answer (score 0):

This error happens when the **post method is not delivered properly**.

Use your developer tools to check the HTML elements and make sure there are quotes anywhere needed.

If you add your HTML code I will be able to assist you further.